# How can I extract information from parquet files with Spark/PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have to read in N parquet files, sort all the data by a particular column, and then write out the sorted data in N parquet files.  While I'm processing this data, I also have to produce an index that will later be used to optimize the access to the data in these files.  The index will also be written as a parquet file.

For the sake of example, let's say that the data represents grocery store transactions and we want to create an index by product to transaction so that we can quickly know which transactions have cottage cheese, for example, without having to scan all N parquet files.

I'm pretty sure I know how to do the first part, but I'm struggling with how to extract and tally the data for the index while reading in the N parquet files.

For the moment, I'm using PySpark locally on my box, but this solution will eventually run on AWS, probably in AWS Glue.

Any suggestions on how to create the index would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is already built into spark SQL.  In SQL use "distribute by" or pyspark: paritionBy before writing and it will group the data as you wish on your behalf.  Even if you don't use a partitioning strategy Parquet has [predicate pushdown](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.3/topics/cdh_ig_predicate_pushdown_parquet.html) that does lower level filtering.  (Actually if you are using AWS, you likely don't want to use partitioning and should stick with large files that use predicate pushdown. Specifically because s3 scanning of directories is slow and should be avoided.)

Basically, great idea, but this is already in place.

Comment: querying the parquet files happens via a redshift connection to AWS Glue.  We have 16000+ files that are organized sub-optimally for query optimization and I've been tasked to do a proof of concept to reorganized them by transactionId ranges and then to create index a separate index that redshift can join from to help optimize the queries.  So, the queries are not happening from Spark.  I'm just using PySpark to do this work.

Comment: using distribute by would be the way to ensure your data is grouped the way that you are interested in.  I would also suggest where possible using as few files as possible.  S3 has a performance issue with multiple small files.  Try to create large files and use processing power to filter data.  The file lookup is one of the performance degradation points.  (which is sounds like you are trying to work around, so you are likley aware of)